# ANTLR 4: Parsing grammar

Tags: java, antlr4

I want to parse some data from AppleSoft Basic script.
I choose ANTLR and download this grammar: [jvmBasic](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/basic/jvmBasic.g4)

I'm trying to extract function name without parameters:

```
return parser.prog().line(0).amprstmt(0).statement().getText();
```

but it returns PRINT"HELLO" e.g full expression except the line number
Here is string i want to parse:

> 10 PRINT "Hello!"

Comment: Note: full class is:
[link](http://pastebin.com/bRbRhhLt)

Comment: malarzm, thanks for edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question really depends on your ANTLR program implementation but if you are using a treewalker/listener you probably want to be targeting the rule for the specific tokens not the entire "statement" rule which is circular and encompasses many types of statement :

```
//each line can have one to many amprstmt's
line
   : (linenumber ((amprstmt (COLON amprstmt?)*) | (COMMENT | REM)))
   ;

amprstmt
   : (amperoper? statement) //encounters a statement here
   | (COMMENT | REM)
   ;
//statements can be made of 1 to many sub statements
statement
   : (CLS | LOAD | SAVE | TRACE | NOTRACE | FLASH | INVERSE | GR | NORMAL | SHLOAD | CLEAR | RUN | STOP | TEXT | HOME | HGR | HGR2)
   | prstmt
   | printstmt1 //the print rule
   //MANY MANY OTHER RULES HERE TOO LONG TO PASTE........
   ;
//the example rule that occurs when the token's "print" is encountered
printstmt1
   : (PRINT | QUESTION) printlist?
   ;

printlist
   : expression (COMMA | SEMICOLON)? printlist*
   ;
```

As you can see from the BNF type grammar here the statement rule in this grammar includes the rules for a print statement as well as every other type of statement so it will encompass 10, PRINT and hello and subsequently return the text with the getText() method when any of these are encountered in your case, everything but linenumber which is a rule outside of the statement rule.

If you want to target these specific rules to handle what happens when they are encountered you most likely want to add functionality to each of the methods ANTLR generates for each rule by extending the jvmBasiListener class as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/mattmcd/5425206)

example:

```
-jvmBasicListener.java
-extended to jvmBasicCustomListener.java

void enterPrintstmt1(jvmBasicParser.Printstmt1Context ctx){
System.out.println(ctx.getText());
}
```

However if all this is setup and you are just wanting to return a string value etc using the single line you have then trying to access the methods at a lower level by addressing the child nodes of statement may work amprstmt->statement->printstmt1->value :

```
 return  parser.prog().line().amprstmt(0).statement().printstmt1().getText();
```

Just to maybe narrow my answer slightly, the rules specifically that address your input "10 PRINT "HELLO" " would be :

```
linenumber (contains Number) , statement->printstmt1 and statement->datastmt->datum (contains STRINGLITERAL)
```

So as shown above the linenumber rule exists on its own and the other 2 rules that defined your text are children of statement, which explains outputting everything except the line number when getting the statement rules text.

Addressing each of these and using getText() rather than an encompassing rule such as statement may give you the result you are looking for.

---

I will update to address your question since the answer may be slightly longer, the easiest way in my opinion to handle specific rules rather than generating a listener or visitor would be to implement actions within your grammar file rules like this :

```
printstmt1
   : (PRINT | QUESTION) printlist? {System.out.println("Print"); //your java code }
   ;
```

This would simply allow you to address each rule and perform whichever java action you would wish to carry out. You can then simply compile your code with something like :

```
java -jar antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar jvmBasic.g4 -visitor
```

After this you can simply run your code however you wish, here is an example:

```
import JVM1.jvmBasicLexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;


public class Jvm extends jvmBasicBaseVisitor<Object> {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jvmBasicLexer lexer = new jvmBasicLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("10 PRINT \"Hello!\""));
        jvmBasicParser parser = new jvmBasicParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTree tree = parser.prog();
    }

}
```

The output for this example would then be just :

```
Print
```

You could also incorporate whatever Java methods you like within the grammar to address each rule encountered and either develop your own classes and methods to handle it or directly print it out a result.

---

### Update

Just to address the latest question now :
`parser.line().linenumber().getText()` - For line Number, as line is not part of a statement

`parser.prog().line(0).amprstmt(0).statement().printstmt1().PR‌​INT().getText()` - For PRINT as it is isolated in printstmt1, however does not include CLR in the rule

`parser.prog().line(0).amprstmt(0).statement().printstmt1().pr‌intlist().expression().getText()` - To get the value "hello" as it is part of an expression contained within the printstmt1 rule.

:) Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but can i using only antlr4 generator(without implementing own listeners) simply parse only one statement?

Comment: I updated the answer to address your question since it was too long for a comment and wanted to include an example, i hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks :) it very helpful.

Comment: Dean219, i try to compile grammar using -visitor parameter but i get errors. Here is screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/ToBZcgjTt7XFr

Comment: Ok there is quite a number of errors there probably due to the arrangement of the packages firstly. After i compile my grammar using antlr's jar i usually copy all the files into netbeans and have to manually correct the package name at the top of each file generated, however in the screenshot your current file opened's package is not invalid or underlined for some reason. The most likely reason would be one of the classes your are implementing or extending's package has not been changed. Try going into all the files antlr generates and make sure they are all in package com.monobogdan.compler.

Comment: It compilings succeful, errors in @override.
But i can't extract function name. here is my code:
ParseTree tree = parser.prog().line(0).statement(0).getText()

Comment: Well firsty try and figure out the override error, what does it explain is the reason for the override error when you hover over the underlined override?

Comment: after restart netbeans, no errors. But i can't get only function name

Comment: What error does it respond with when you try to use the method : parser.prog().line(0).statement(0).getText()? just null on its own?

Comment: No, it return PRINT"HELLO". i.e original string without line number.

Comment: To print the line number you would have to use something like parser.prog().line(0).linenumber.getText() as it does not exist within the statement rule.

Comment: Actually i got that wrong line exists higher up, use something like parser.line().linenumber().getText()  as it does not exist within the statement rule.

Comment: I not need line number. I need command name such as CLS or PRINT

Comment: Just to clarify more you can use System.out.println(parser.line().linenumber().getText()); //to get line number , System.out.println(parser.prog().line(0).amprstmt(0).statement().printstmt1().PRINT().getText()); // and this to get text "PRINT"  and          System.out.println(parser.prog().line(0).amprstmt(0).statement().printstmt1().printlist().expression().getText()); //to get the content "Hello", however using any of these will consume the line resulting in a second action on the line being "null"

Comment: parser.prog().line(0).amprstmt(0).statement().printstmt1().PR‌​INT().getText() is what you are looking for, however since both CLS and print commands are different and from different rules contained in the statement rule, this will only work if print is used.

Comment: I need to parse and CLS and PRINT and QUEST functions.

Comment: This is more or less why ANTLR includes a listener and visitor, so you can implement your own implementations for every single rule by overriding and implementing its generated listener/visitor class as mentioned in my original answer. Your solution now would be if you want to handle CLS,Print and Quest to generate a listener from ANTLR and implement the jvmBaseListener class in your own custom listener and override the relevant rules such as printstmt1 to perform whatever action you wish with the Context ctx parameter.

Comment: Yes but this is a print out of your entire line essentially, with the exception of the line number since your are printing the value of the statement node which contains both printstmt1 and an epression as defined in the grammar file. So if you want to use separate them you will need to either use the lines as i said and address each node lower than statement such as printstmt1 and expression and get the text from those nodes or if you are looking for this instance specifically to split them you could use a regex if its just a very specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm writing simple compiler for simple basic like language. May be, substr?
i.e: str = parser.line.getText();

str = str.subString(str.indexOf(' '), str.length() - str.indexOf(' '));

Comment: Yes some sort of string splitting or maybe a pattern/matcher would be the fastest and most stable solution for what you are trying to do : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm